# Apache Ignite - how to close client

Tags: ignite

I start a Client to connect remote Server.
It involves a lot of computation.
Then the Client accidental disconnected.
However the Client's computation is still running on remote Server.
has a way to close it?

Answer (score 0):

It will eventually happen when socket timeout is reached, I guess.